# If $F_{\mu_n}(x) \longmapsto F_{\mu}(x) \hspace{0.1cm}\forall x \in D$ countable dense then $\mu_n \longmapsto \mu$ vaguely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Given $\mu$ a finite measure and $(\mu_n)_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ measure of probability on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ then the following statements holds :

*Theorem : If $F_{\mu_n}(x) \longmapsto F_{\mu}(x) \hspace{0.1cm}\forall x \in D$ countable dense then $\mu_n \longmapsto \mu$ vaguely*.

I remember the definition of vague convergence : $\mu_n \longmapsto \mu$ vaguely if $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \int f d\mu_n = \int f d\mu \hspace{0.1cm} \forall f \hspace{0.1cm}\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$.

The proof of the theorem is an approximation argument, noting that if $f = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_i \mathbb{1}_{(x_i,x_{i+1}]}$ with $x_i \in D$ then $$\int f d\mu_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_i(F_{\mu_n}(x_{i+1})-F_{\mu_n}(x_{i})) \overset{n}{\longmapsto} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_i(F_{\mu}(x_{i+1})-F_{\mu}(x_{i}))= \int f d\mu$$

So the problem is to approximate every $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ with functions belonging to the class $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_i \mathbb{1}_{(x_i,x_{i+1}]} : x_i \in D$.

I know that if $ f\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ then $ \exists\hspace{0.1cm} K$ compact such that $f|{_{\mathbb{R}-K}} = 0$ so $f$ is uniformely continuos on $K$, but how to procede from here ?

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $\delta >0$ sch that $|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon$ if $|x-y| \leq \delta$. There exists $N$ such that $f(x)=0$ if $|x|>N$. Let $\{x_i\}$ be a partition of $[-N,N]$ such that $x_{i+1}-x_i <\delta$ for each $i$. Let $g =\sum a_i1_{(x_i,x_{i+1}]}$ where $a_i=f(x_i)$. Then $|f(x)-g(x)| <\epsilon$ for all $x$.

Comment: When you write $\lvert f(x)-g(x) \rvert$ do you mean the infinity norm ?

Comment: @jacopoburelli $\|f-g\|_{\infty} \leq \epsilon$ if and only if $|f(x)-g(x)| \leq \epsilon$ for all $x$.